# Easy way to identify page requests in Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I'd like to identify requests for page in Sitecore from code running toward the end of the httpRequestBegin pipeline.

The reason is [I want to redirect to an old browser page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577260/browser-upgrade-page-redirect-vs-privacy-mode) but I don't want the redirect to happen for media item requests or static content requests.

Here's what I was thinking of doing:

```
private static bool IsPageRequest(HttpRequestArgs args)
{
    return Context.Item != null &&
           Context.Item.Axes.IsDescendantOf(args.GetItem(Context.Site.RootPath));
}
```

But it looks suboptimal to me. Is there a more performant way to check this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
private static bool IsPageRequest(HttpRequestArgs args)
{
    return Context.Item != null && Context.Item.Paths.IsContentItem;
}
```

This seems to be a little more performant.  Using Reflector, `IsContentItem` returns true when the item's path starts with `/sitecore/content/`.

Comment: Context.Item returns false for requests /sitecore/shell. Is there a better way to identify sitecore native pages request?

Answer (score 3):

A suggestion not to annoy the hell outta your users: Why don't you show an overlay div with the upgrade notification and can cover all/some of the page that the user lands on. Add in a [X] to allow them to close and return to whatever they wanted to do?

You could add a static binding to the layout.aspx page and add a Sitecore rule which checks for the presence of your cookie to decide whether to output the message div/content:

- [Personalizing Statically Based Components with the Sitecore Rules Engine](http://webcmd.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/personalizing-staticlly-based-componenets-with-the-sitecore-rules-engine/)
- [Sitecore Rules Engine: How to create a custom condition](http://newguid.net/sitecore/2011/sitecore-rules-engine-how-to-create-a-custom-condition/)
- [Sitecore Rules Engine and Conditional Rendering](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Sitecore-Rules-Engine-and-Conditional-Rendering.aspx)

There is some further information on the 
[Sitecore httpRequestBegin Pipeline - In Detail](http://insitecore.tumblr.com/post/37734162227/sitecore-httprequestbegin-pipeline-in-detail) if you still want to proceed down this route. It's really going to depend on your exact requirments. Do you want to redirect without any checks, i.e. invalid item, no layout set etc?

If so then after the relevant processor, or otherwise I would look to add your processor immediately after `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.IgnoreList` or `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.FilterUrlExtensions` (although this is deprecated and purely added for backwards compatibility) in `<httpRequestBegin>`.

Your media items should have been handled already at this stage by `<preprocessRequest>`.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely agree, and I would've gladly gone down the conditional rendering route but for the fact the client insisted on a separate page.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder what planet the clients live on when they insist on crazy requirements like this!